Length of unicode emoji varies
I build a webapp and one specific user uses a chef-emoji (https://emojipedia.org/de/koch#technical) in his username.
At some point in my code I need to get the length of his username string.
I noticed that in test-env ‍.length is 5. (firefox 128.0.3)
In prod-env ‍-length is 7. (firefox 115.13.0)
html charset is utf8.
How can the length of the same string be different in two different environments?
I read this
https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/
which wasn't very new to me, and this
https://dmitripavlutin.com/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-unicode/
which was quite interesting.
However, ‍ consisting of 3 code points and two of them being surrogate pairs, I assume length of 5 should be the correct answer.
How ist the length 7 in prod-environment?

Unicode is a variable-width character encoding.

This question is similar to: How to count the correct length of a string with emojis in javascript?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ControlAltDel my question is about the length of one and the same string being different in two different environments. And not about how to count graphemes

@Mr.Polywhirl Unicode itself is not a character encoding. UTFs are character encodings of Unicode.

The string "‍" consists of 3 Unicode code points:

U+1F468 MAN ().
U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER.
U+1F373 COOKING ().

This string can be encoded into either:

A sequence of 11 UTF-8 code units: F0 9F 91 A8 / E2 80 8D / F0 9F 8D B3.
A sequence of 5 UTF-16 code units (or 10 bytes): D83D DC68 / 200D / D83C DF73
A sequence of 3 UTF-32 code units (or 12 bytes): 0001F468 / 0000200D / 0001F373

JavaScript stores strings natively as UTF-16 code units, and so should use interpretation #2, in which the string is 5 units long.
> "‍".length
< 5

But I can't think of any interpretation of "length" in which the string is exactly 7 units long.  I can only speculate that your "prod" environment is somehow inserting an extra invisible character or two that's throwing off the .length value.
Try logging the exact character codes using something like:
const emoji = "‍";
for (let i = 0; i < emoji.length; i++) {
    console.log(emoji.charCodeAt(i).toString(16));
}

to see exactly what's in your string.

Thank you. I did isolate the emoji and obtained the length. The difference was still there. Still your information was useful to me.

I found the difference. The user's emoji was white skinned which added two more code units to it  facepalm
